# Get last page of GitHub Search Api result in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, github-api

I'm making a new iOS (swift) app to test some concepts, and I'm using the GitHub Serach API to retrieve a list of filtered repositories.

The request is working fine so far, but I'm having trouble understanding the pagination process and how to know I reached the end of the results.

For what I saw, the Search API returns a maximum of 1k results, broke in pages of 100 maximum results. But the field in the returned json with the total count shows way more available results (I imagine that it shows the total repositories that satisfy the query and not the maximum available for return in the API).

The only way I found so far to obtain information about the pages (and the pagination process) in [GitHub Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) comes in the header of the response, like:

```
Status: 200 OK
Link: <https://api.github.com/resource?page=2>; rel="next",
  <https://api.github.com/resource?page=5>; rel="last"
X-RateLimit-Limit: 20
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 19
```

Anyone can suggest the best approach to detect the end of the pages in this case?
Should I try to parse the information from the header or infer it somehow based on the returned json? I even got the "Link" header value but don't know how to parse it.